# React tailwind css -right position show scroll bar

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have sticky box with show hide button as shown in image. It is working but if I tried to hide there is horizontal scroll bar and can see the box as shown in image 2. To colapse the box, I change right-0 to -right-24. Is there anyway not to show the horizontal scroll bar.

Image 1 -: showing sticky bar and can click setting icon to hide the bar. There is no horizontal scroll bar.

[image]

Image 2 -: after hide the bar, horizontal scroll bar is appeared and can see the box when I scroll.

[image]

```
const TrackPage = () => {

  const handleMenuCollapse = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setColapse(!colapse);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div
          className={`flex w-24 h-96 absolute top-[calc((100vh-384px)/2)]  ${
            colapse ? "-right-24" : "right-0"
          } " bg-primary rounded-b-lg items-center justify-center`}
         >
          <div
            className="flex w-12 h-12 absolute -top-0 -left-12 cursor-pointer bg-primary rounded-l-lg items-center justify-center"
        onClick={handleMenuCollapse}
          >
            <SettingIcon />
           </div>
          Setting
         </div>
 
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TrackPage;
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "./components/header";
import SideMenu from "./components/side_menu";
import AppRoutes from "./routes";
import withUser from "./hocs/with_user";
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthProvider, setAccessToken } from 
"./auth/auth_provider";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import AppContext from "./components/app_context";
import "./i18n";
import "./App.css";

function App(props) {
   const [colapse, setColapse] = useState(isMobile);
   const [sideBarFull] = useState(true);
   const location = useLocation();

  const IsNormalPage = () => {
     const blankPages = ["/login"];

     for (let i = 0; i < blankPages.length; i++) {
       if (location.pathname.startsWith(blankPages[i])) return 
 false;
    }
     return true;
   };

  useEffect(() => {
     if (props.user) setAccessToken(props.user.t);
   }, []);

  const PageHeader = () => {
     return (
       <div className="h-[72px] w-full flex items-center align-middle justify-center bg-neutral shadow">
         <div className="w-full text-center">
          <Header />
         </div>
        </div>
      );
    };


  return (
     <AuthProvider user={props.user}>
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
           colapse: colapse,
           setColapse: setColapse,
          }}
         >
        <div className="relative w-full min-h-screen h-full">
          <div className="flex flex-row min-h-screen">
            <div className="w-auto z-0 ">
               <div className="flex-1 w-full max-h-screen mx-auto text-lg h-full shadow-lg bg-white overflow-y-auto">
            {IsNormalPage() && <SideMenu showFullMenu={sideBarFull} />}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full max-h-screen flex flex-col z-10">
          {IsNormalPage() && <PageHeader />}
          <div className="flex-1 w-full max-h-screen mx-auto text-lg h-full shadow-lg bg-white overflow-y-auto">
            <Toaster />
            <AppRoutes />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </AppContext.Provider>
</AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default withUser(App);
```

Comment: Hi Alex can you show me where you imported `TrackPage` and what is its parent?

Comment: @Dhaifallah I have edit and added App.jsx. TrackPage is coming from route. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow-x-hidden` to your wrapper div that has ` overflow-y-auto`?

Comment: @EdLucas yes, I did but no effect. Still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution for this

First let's divide this section into two sections (the settings icon and the bigger div that you want to hide)

Then add this to the big div className: `${colapse ? "hidden" : "right-0"}` so it will just be hidden instead of `-right-24`

and for the icon div add this to its className:`${colapse ? "animate-pulse right-0": "right-24"}` the animation is of course optional I just added it.

This is the code but I forgot and named the component `Side.jsx` instead of `TrackPage.jsx`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Side() {
  const [colapse, setColapse] = useState(true);
  const handleMenuCollapse = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setColapse(!colapse);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {/** the big div */}
      <div
        className={`flex w-24 h-96  bg-indigo-500 absolute top-[calc((100vh-384px)/2)]  ${
          colapse ? "hidden" : "right-0"
        } " bg-primary rounded-b-lg items-center justify-center`}
      >
        Setting
      </div>

      {/** the icon div */}
      <div
        className={`flex w-12 absolute  top-[calc((100vh-384px)/2)] h-12 bg-indigo-500
                ${colapse ? "animate-pulse right-0" : "right-24"}
                cursor-pointer bg-primary rounded-l-lg items-center justify-center`}
        onClick={handleMenuCollapse}
      >
        <div className="w-5 h-5 bg-white rounded-full " />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Side;
```

take a look [**Live**](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-yonath-cpgocm?file=/src/App.js) on codesandbox.

Comment: It is perfect and love the animate-pulse too. I tried to put hidden but setting button is hidden too. Separating two div is solution. Thanks for the perfect example.

Comment: @AlexAung Glad that helped, I was lucky, Happy coding :)